# R shiny subset by quantile

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create interactive visualisation (using R shiny) but I have a problem, I want to create an interactive barplot, where user is able to select (like subset) data from my df, I want to have a plot of quantiles (from 0.75 to 1, by 0.01). So user can select using slider which quantile of data he wants to see.
for example - 10000 value in my column is 0.75 percentile, so when user selects 0.75 percentile order on slider, R shiny generates barplot for this column with values from min value to 10000.
same for 0.76 etc...

I've tried but i don't know how to set this, i just can do barplot with number of breaks, but don't know how to set max value like in my desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You can add some selectInput for the column choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Iris Quantile"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("quantile",
                        "Quantile",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 1,
                        value = 0.75,
                        step = 0.01)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filter_iris <- function(column, value){
    
    quantile_value <- quantile(iris %>% pull(all_of(column)), value)
    
    iris %>% filter(.data[[column]] < quantile_value)
    
  }
  
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = filter_iris("Petal.Length", input$quantile), aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
        geom_bar()
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello, that's exactly what i've been looking for, thank you so much! :)